# Showing which classes are recurrent and which are transient

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, stochastic-analysis

If I have a Markov chain on states {0,1,2,3,4,5}

$$
\mathbf{a} = \matrix{~ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
              0 & 1/3 & 0 & 2/3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
              1 & 0 & 0.25 & 0 & 0.75 & 0 & 0 \\
              2 & 2/3 & 0 & 1/3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
              3 & 0 & 0.20 & 0 & 0.80 & 0 & 0 \\
              4 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0 & 0 & 0.25 & 0.25 \\
              5 & 1/6 & 1/6 & 1/6 & 1/6 & 1/6 & 1/6
              }
$$

and

$$
\mathbf{b} = \matrix{~ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
              0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
              1 & 0 & 0.75 & 0.25 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
              2 & 0 & 1/8 & 7/8 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
              3 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0 & 1/8 & 3/8 & 0 \\
              4 & 1/3 & 0 & 1/6 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0 \\
              5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
              }
$$

I am supposed to find all communicating classes and specify which classes are transient and which are recurrent.

I found the classes for a to be: {0,2},{1,3},{4,5}

and the classes for b to be: {0},{5},{1,2},{3,4}

but I am having a hard time showing which are recurrent and which are transient.  Can anyone help with this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your book should have some theorems that will help...